# CSS: ¿Como podria curvear las puntas de una imagen en forma de hexagono?

Tags: html, css

Estuve tratando con el metodo de "clip-path" pero no encuentro una forma para curvear las puntas.
Actualemte tengo esto

```css
.hexagono-final { 
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 50%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 50%);
     }
```

```html
<img  src="img/perfil_tono.jpg" alt="" width="200px" class="img-fluid hexagono-final">
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí un ejemplo:

[Código Original](https://github.com/tarobjtu/hexagon)

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.hexagon .hexagon-shape {
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: -60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 48px 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 208px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg) scale(0.5);
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.hexagon .hexagon-shape *,
.hexagon .hexagon-shape *:before {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.hexagon .hexagon-shape .hexagon-shape-inner {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.hexagon .hexagon-shape:first-child .hexagon-shape-inner:before {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/any');
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon hexagon-button">
  <div class="hexagon-shape content-panel">
    <div class="hexagon-shape-inner">
      <div class="hexagon-shape-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```